# MySQL Python connector not giving any error, yet values are not inserted into the database?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm practicing SQL on LeetCode (e.g., https://leetcode.com/problems/game-play-analysis-ii/) and would like to reproduce failed test cases locally. LeetCode provides JSON with table values for each test case which I'd like to convert programmatically into `INSERT INTO` statements.

I've created an `Activity2` table in `mydatabase` with four columns, `player_id`, `device_id`, `event_date`, and `games_played`:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Activity2;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| player_id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| device_id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| event_date   | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| games_played | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Activity2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATABASE();
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| mydatabase |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then try running the following script (after running `pip install mysql-connector-python`):

```
import json
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='myuser',
    password='mypassword',
    host='127.0.0.1',
    database='mydatabase',
    port=3306)

cursor = connection.cursor()

with open('game_play_analysis_testcase.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played in data['rows']['Activity']:
    query = \
f"""
INSERT INTO Activity2 (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played)
VALUES ({player_id}, {device_id}, {event_date!r}, {games_played});
"""
    print(query)
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(err.msg)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

The structure of the JSON file is such that this works; for example, the `print` statement produces the following (partial) output:

```
INSERT INTO Activity2 (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played)
VALUES (85, 99, '2019-02-27', 45);


INSERT INTO Activity2 (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played)
VALUES (78, 34, '2019-01-16', 87);


INSERT INTO Activity2 (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played)
VALUES (58, 31, '2019-02-25', 52);
```

The problem is that if I run this script, I find that the `Activity2` table is still empty afterward.

I would think that since no error was raised/printed, this should work. I'm quite sure that the credentials I used are correct. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to commit after your inserts. This link says the MySQL Python connector does not autocommit.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html

Maybe do connection.commit() after your for loop with the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure that this is correct without knowing more about your database, but it's likely that you just need to commit your results. See here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html

The default behavior of mysql.connector is to *not* autocommit, so if your database is transactional then you'll need to execute `connection.commit()` before you close the connection. Or you could do so after each `cursor.execute` if you want to ensure that those transactions are committed at that point.